# SSRS export tablixes to different Excel sheets

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have 2 tablixes on one report. I want to export them to different sheets (one tablix one sheet).

How to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding a page break between both tables.

Add a rectangle between the tablixes and set the Rectangle property: `Add a Page break before` or `Add a page break after`.

**UPDATE:**

You can set the Name of the page by setting the Rectangle `PageName` property.

[image]

> When you export a report to Excel, the report pages that were created
>   by page breaks are exported to different worksheets.

[REFERENCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255234.aspx#Anchor_4)

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Perfect. After your help, I found that Tablix itself has ability to have page break before.

Can you also help how to name the sheets? Thanks once more.

Comment: @elninho, check [this](http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2011/03/23/where-the-sheets-have-a-name-ssrs-excel-export/), Also [this](http://bidn.com/blogs/bretupdegraff/bidn-blog/234/new-features-of-ssrs-2008-r2-part-1-naming-excel-sheets-when-exporting-reports) could help you.